# Переместить div, в div в другой компонент

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

Есть сайт, на нем есть страницы. На некоторых страницах в шапке должны быть кнопки, шапка сделана как отдельный компонент.
Вот класс в файле header

```
<div className='center_block'>
//target
</div>
```

А вот как сделать сам телепорт из другого файла, незнаю(

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, вам надо разместить контент с шапки внутри файла. Для этого вам нужно в вашем компоненте с шапкой прописать:

```
export default Header
```

А в файле, где нужно разместить компонент:

```
import Header from "путь к компоненту";
```

После вставить компонент:

```
<Header/>
```

Comment: мне нужно в шапку сделать телепорт из другого компонента, тоесть из файла dashboard в файл header поместить кнопки

Comment: @peter Андрій Наумець, к сожалению вы не скинули всей структуры чтобы можно было в полной мере понять и разобрать ваш вопрос, но как я понял, способ, указанный выше подойдет для вас. В файле dashboard у вас есть кнопки, а значит эти кнопки находятся в какой-то компоненте => вам нужно экспортировать компоненту и импортировать её в ваш header. После импорта её нужно будет разместить в коде там, где вам нужно, пример: <Header/>

Comment: для того, чтобы экспортировать компоненту нужно написать: export default 'название компоненты без кавычек', для точно чтобы импортировать: import 'название компоненты без кавычек' from 'путь до вашей компоненты в кавычках'

Comment: https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/teleport.html есть ли такой аналог на react?

Comment: @АндрійНаумець - есть такое свойство как `Portal`, ссылка: [https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html], но я для такого использую библиотеку `react-teleporter`, ссылка: [https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-teleporter]